# template lambda expression in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I am upgrading to C++ 11 and have basic idea about lambda expression as mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/lambda-expressions-in-cpp?view=vs-2019

I have following doubts about the code below captured from http://project-thrill.org/

The following program counts the number of occurrences of each unique word in a text

```
void WordCount(thrill::Context& ctx, std::string input, std::string output) 
{
    using Pair = std::pair<std::string, size_t>;
    auto word_pairs = ReadLines(ctx, input)
                            .template FlatMap<Pair>(
                            // flatmap lambda: split and emit each word
                                [](const std::string& line, auto emit)
                                {
                                    Split(line, ’ ’, [&](std::string_view sv)
                                    {
                                        emit(Pair(sv.to_string(), 1));
                                    });
                                });
    word_pairs.ReduceByKey(
        // key extractor: the word string
        [](const Pair& p) { return p.first; },
        // commutative reduction: add counters
        [](const Pair& a, const Pair& b) 
        {
            return Pair(a.first, a.second + b.second);
        })
    .Map([](const Pair& p)
    {
        return p.first + ": " + std::to_string(p.second); 
    }).WriteLines(output);
}
```

> first question  what is `.template FlatMap`

is `FlatMap` a template type lambda function which is operating on return of `ReadLines`?

> inside `FlatMap<Pair>` how the value is geting passed to `(const std::string& line, auto emit)` and who passes the value ?

---

> inside `ReduceByKey` function, to the argument `[](const Pair& p)` of lambda function, how value is getting passed ?

Comment: Your first question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords

Comment: FlatMap is not a lambda, it takes a function as parameter and that parameter is a lambda that will be wrapped as a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is `.template FlatMap`

It's a syntactic necessity, to indicate that `FlatMap` is a template member, and that the `<` is part of an explicit template argument and not a comparison operator.

> is `FlatMap` a template type lambda function which is operating on return of `ReadLines`?`

That's not a thing. `FlatMap` is a template member function, and it receives a [*Callable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable) as it's sole parameter. Here it is called with a lambda expression.

> inside `FlatMap<Pair>` how the value is geting passed to `(const std::string& line, auto emit)` and who passes the value ?

The body of `FlatMap`. like how `emit` is called inside the lambda. Presumably it is called once for each line in the input, and generates multiple Pair as output from each input line.

> inside `ReduceByKey` function, to the argument `[](const Pair& p)` of lambda function, how value is getting passed ?

The same way. `ReduceByKey` has two *Callable* arguments, and calls them based on the member's of `word_pairs` (which is the result of `FlatMap`)

It will categorise each item it sees by the first function, and then combine within each category with the second function.